# How can I use jQuery with selenium execute_script method?

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, selenium

How can I use jQuery with the selenium `execute_script` method, if the current page isn't already using jQuery?

For example:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
driver.execute_script('$("#id").wrap("<h1></h1>")')
```

I've tried adding a script like this:

```
driver.execute_script(
"var jquery_script = document.createElement('script'); 
jquery_script.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js';
document.findElementsByTag('head')[0].appendChild(jquery_script)"
)
```

But I get errors saying that the jquery_script variable is undefined.

Comment: you could use javascript to insert `<script src="http//.../path/to/jquery.js"></script>` to load `jQuery`

Comment: [Load jQuery with Javascript and use jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10113366/load-jquery-with-javascript-and-use-jquery)

Comment: @furas thanks, but I've already tried that and couldn't manage to get it to work.  I added an update showing my attempt.

Comment: you have two mistakes: `getElementsByTagName` instead of `findElementsByTag` and you have to put it in triple `""" """` or you have to put Javascript in one line. And then it runs correctly but still it doesn't create `$` which you can use in next script. Using code from link (in answer marked as accepted) I could run my code with `$`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems way better to load a local jquery:

```
with open('jquery.js', errors='ignore') as f:
  driver.execute_script(f.read())

title = driver.execute_script('return $("title").text()')
```

It's faster and you don't have to worry about timing issues.

Comment: I'm not sure, I think the minified version had some weird unicode in it.

Comment: would I download the file to store locally as jquery.js from somewhere here: https://jquery.com/download/  ? +

Comment: @Qharr, yes I used the latest compressed production version but it shouldn't matter.

Comment: Make sure you execute this after you do driver.get(url)

Answer (score 2):

You have two mistakes:

- `getElementsByTagName` instead of `findElementsByTag`
- you have to put it in triple `""" """` or you have to put Javascript in one line.

After this it adds `jQuery` but it need few lines more to use `$`

First: it needs some time to load `jQuery` so it needs `time.sleep()`

Second: this code doesn't create automatically `$` and it needs `$ = window.jQuery;`

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57941221/how-can-i-use-jquery-with-selenium-execute-script-method'
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

driver.execute_script("""var jquery_script = document.createElement('script'); 
jquery_script.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jquery_script);""")

time.sleep(0.5) # time to load jQuery library
driver.execute_script('$ = window.jQuery;')

driver.execute_script('$("h1").wrap("<i></i>")')
#driver.execute_script('$ = window.jQuery;$("h1").wrap("<i></i>")')
```

---

You can also use `jquery_script.onload` in first script to run code which will create `$`

```
jquery_script.onload = function(){var $ = window.jQuery;};
```

but it still need `time.sleep()` before you use `$`.

I took this from [Load jQuery with Javascript and use jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10113366/load-jquery-with-javascript-and-use-jquery)

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57941221/how-can-i-use-jquery-with-selenium-execute-script-method'
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

driver.execute_script("""var jquery_script = document.createElement('script'); 
jquery_script.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js';
jquery_script.onload = function(){var $ = window.jQuery;};
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jquery_script);""")

time.sleep(0.5) # time to load jQuery library

driver.execute_script('$("h1").wrap("<i></i>")')
```

---

Eventually you can run all in `onload` and then you don't need `time.sleep()`

```
jquery_script.onload = function(){var $ = window.jQuery; $("h1").wrap("<i></i>");};
```

Full code

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57941221/how-can-i-use-jquery-with-selenium-execute-script-method'
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

driver.execute_script("""var jquery_script = document.createElement('script'); 
jquery_script.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js';
// jquery_script.onload = function(){var $ = window.jQuery; $("h1").wrap("<i></i>");};
jquery_script.onload = function(){
  var $ = window.jQuery; 
  $("h1").wrap("<i></i>");
};
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jquery_script);""")
```

Comment: thanks!  I was getting `document.getElementById` mixed up with the selenium `find_element_by_id` method.