# Python Beatifulsoup cannot use the result of selenium correctly

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to parse a webpage using beautifulsoup. I can see that the page is correctly loaded in selenium using chromedriver but the final result is null and when I see the parsed page print in beautifulsoup it does not show the whole page that selenium shows in its automated browser.

The code that I'm using for this purpose is:

```
page_soup = soup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
print (page_soup)
containers = page_soup.findAll("div", class_="row ploc-l-row--gutterV flex-wrap flex-align-start flex-center-vertical")
print (len(containers))
```

I need to access each partner information, but the result is null. The page that I'm working on is

```
https://locatr.cloudapps.cisco.com/WWChannels/LOCATR/openBasicSearch.do;jsessionid=8CDF9284D014CFF911CB8E6F81812619
```

Comment: Which elements on the page are you trying to find with `page_soup.findAll`? I have run your selector on the page link you provided but it is bringing back no results, so selector is probably wrong.

Comment: As you know, the page is a search page with multiple results. I want to access to each result. For example when you search for china, it will shows 5 results in first page, I want to access to each result. As I can see each result is within a div with a class with some classnames that I mentioned above.

Comment: I have written some modified BeautifulSoup code from what you provided, and changed the selector. This code will retrieve the `name` of every partner listed on the search results page.

Comment: I get no results found when loading that link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result is loaded using javascript. You need to wait until the search results to load before **scraping**. Here is a working example,

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import time

url = 'https://locatr.cloudapps.cisco.com/WWChannels/LOCATR/openBasicSearch.do'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/Selenium/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(url)
SearchString = 'CALIFORNIA'
Location = driver.find_element_by_name("location")
Location.send_keys(SearchString)
#search = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_any_elements_located(By.XPATH,"//li//span[contains(text(),'"+SearchString+"')]"))
#search.click()
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li//span[contains(text(),'"+SearchString+"')]").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("searchBtn").click()

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,'searchResultsList')))
time.sleep(3)
page_soup = soup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
print(page_soup.prettify())
containers = page_soup.findAll("div", class_="row ploc-l-row--gutterV flex-wrap flex-align-start flex-center-vertical")
print (len(containers))

driver.close()
```

The results is **5**

Comment: Thank you Suresh, Your code worked well! Can you help me to get the all results in single page ? I mean all the partners not just first 5.

Comment: It would be efficient to get the results using the api. just watch the network tab after the search. There is a getsearch results with all the results.

Comment: FYI it's __scraping__ (and __scrape__, __scraped__, __scraper__) not scrapping, 'Scrapping' means throwing things away like rubbish.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment clarification, I have something retrieve the Partner Name of every partner displayed in search results:

With BeautifulSoup syntax:

```
partnerWebElements = page_soup.findAll(title="View Profile")
```

With just Selenium syntax:

```
partnerWebElements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@title='View Profile']")
```

You can then get text for each Partner name like this:

```
for partnerWebElement in partnerWebElements:
    print(partnerWebElement.text);
```

Comment: I am not sure how the BeautifulSoup syntax works with this, since they do not support XPath. but if you would like to use XPath, you can use `//a[@title='View Profile']`. I am on testing on this page: https://locatr.cloudapps.cisco.com/WWChannels/LOCATR/openBasicSearch.do;jsessionid=8CDF9284D014CFF911CB8E6F81812619

Comment: I updated with another example after checking BeautifulSoup documentation for specific findAll parameters. I will update my answer and add another python example as well, using XPath.

Comment: Thank you Christine, But I still does not get your result. Could you please check out my code, I think there is something different between my code and yours.

Comment: I would refer to @Sureshmani answer that they posted. It looks like a full example and it also retrieves the correct number of results.

Answer (score 1):

FYI that page uses jQuery which makes this easy:

```
driver.execute_script("return $('div[class=\"row ploc-l-row--gutterV flex-wrap flex-align-start flex-center-vertical\"]').length")
```

Comment: you can execute jquery as well via execute_script? +

Comment: Yes in this case it was included in the page but you can also [inject it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57941221/how-can-i-use-jquery-with-selenium-execute-script-method) when it isn't

Comment: wow! Thanks for the link. Be interesting to see if this works across languages with selenium. That is so cool and never thought of it but totally makes sense.

Comment: It should, but it helps if the language has heredocs (looking at Java). jQuery is really the gold standard of html parsers which is why I slowly shake my head when people mix selenium with beautiful soup.