# execute Jquery in selenium Python?

Tags: jquery, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have the problem of running this. I get back an error stating that I have a syntax issue. Ineed help with the Syntax.

> driver.execute_script('$('select[name='condition'] option:eq(30)').prop('selected', true);')
>                                      ^
>   SyntaxError: invalid syntax

```
driver.execute_script("$('select[name='condition'] option:eq(30)').prop('selected', true);")
```

Comment: @AhmadIshaq This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?

Comment: You could build the javascript function that jquery calls and then call the jquery function but I have not yet figured it out and you might as well just use javascript.
Here is the jquery link https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js

Comment: one of the syntax problems here is the unbalanced quotes... you're using single quotes inside of single quotes inside of double quotes.... so 'select[name=' is one quote for open, one quote for close, then condition' is a syntax issue... you can build a string to send to execute_script which makes things a bit more clear... then inside of your string assign js vars to use inside of name= bit...  also note that jQuery must be loaded and ready before using "$"

Comment: @DebanjanB I want to select a value from dropdown but cant select it using selenium so i tried jquery to do that but now i can execute the script but still cant select the required field. Following is the html code for it:

Comment: <label class="json-form-item select condition std variant-select">
<div class="label-wrapper">
<span class="label">condition</span>
</div>
<select
tabindex="1"
name="condition"
class="json-form-input no-js condition">
<option value="" selected >-</option>
<option value="10" >new</option>
<option value="20" >like new</option>
<option value="30">excellent</option>
<option value="40" >good</option>
<option value="50" >fair</option>
<option value="60" >salvage</option>
</select>
</label>

Answer (score 2):

So if jquery is not on the page you need to add it first. I am just appending it to the page below. Then run your code.

```
driver.execute_script("""
var script = document.createElement( 'script' );
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js';
document.head.appendChild(script);
""")


driver.execute_script("$('select[name='condition'] option:eq(30)').prop('selected', true);")
```

More jquery links can be found at: https://code.jquery.com/

Comment: Don't do that, do it [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57941221/how-can-i-use-jquery-with-selenium-execute-script-method). Otherwise you have timing issues.

Comment: @pguardiario what if you do not want to save the `.js` file locally?

Comment: In that case do [like this](https://github.com/pguardiario/scrape_table/blob/master/scrape_table.py)

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.execute_script("""
  $('select[name="condition"] option:eq(30)').prop('selected', true);
""")
```

You can also leave out the quotes in the attribute to be safer (since there are no spaces)

```
driver.execute_script("""
  $('select[name=condition] option:eq(30)').prop('selected', true);
""")
```

Comment: To the Einstein who downvoted this, I'm addressing the syntax error, which is the actual question, rather than injecting jQuery, which is not.